# License Plate Recognition System dpkg: error need an action option

Tags: python, pi-4

I faced an error which is dpkg: error need an action option, when typing `sudo dpkg - -configure –a`  into the raspberry pi based on this tutorial https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/real-time-license-plate-recognition-using-raspberry-pi-and-python , may I know how to solve it?

Comment: Please do not ask a question and then when that is answered edit a new question into the original.   This invalidates existing answers.  You should take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Comment: Ok, thanks letting me know about it, because I am still new to the StackExchange.

Comment: I didn't notice you'd actually already posted that before separately -- people are likely to get annoyed if you post a question twice as well O_O.  Anyway, I don't have an answer for that one, which is part of why it makes sense to keep them separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typo, there should not be spaces between the two dashes.

```
sudo dpkg --configure –a
          ^^ no space there
```

Always a good idea to check the manual page when using a new command: `man dpkg` (see also `man man`).

Comment: Ok, I tried using the answer above, but it says that sudo: dkpg: command not found

Comment: `dpkg` not `dkpg`.  The memonic is that `pkg` is short for "package", which this is part of the package management system.  The `d` is presumably for "Debian" (the creators of it).

Comment: Sorry, but we don't have an infinite discussion style format.  You asked a question and received an answer.  If you now have another question, ask it via the "Ask Question" button top right.